# Accessing from another function an extracted row from an sql table

Tags: php, sql

I have a php auxiliary function called extractFromID() in a file called auxiliary.php which queries a database for a specific line in a table which has a specific ID value and then extracts all the columns from that line.

```
function extractFromID() {
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die ("erro a abrir a ligação.");
    mysql_select_db ("hospitaldatabase");

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' .$_SESSION['listtype']. ' WHERE (ID_' .$_SESSION['listtype']. '="'.$_SESSION['id'].'")';
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     while($rows =  mysql_fetch_array($results){
         extract($rows); 
     }
}
```

From another file, I am trying to access the variables extracted by the function extractFromID() from $rows using

```
<?php

include('auxiliary.php');

extractFromID();
```

Although, I seem to be unable to access the extracted values, since I get undefined index errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like those SESSION variables are not set...

Comment: Where is extract() defined? Also, you do not show where you are trying to access the $rows. After the extractFromID() call? That is a local scope so obviously you can't access it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. It has been deprecated and is no longer maintained! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php /Use mysqli_* or PDO instead! http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I thought that was the problem, but I tried to echo $query and everything was set.

Comment: @cen [extract](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) is a native PHP function

Comment: My bad. Never heared of it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand variable scope. When you declare a variable inside a function, its scope is limited to that function. You can expand its scope by declaring it to be `$GLOBAL` but, in your case, the best solution is to `return` the values you want to use

```
function extractFromID() {
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die ("erro a abrir a ligação.");
    mysql_select_db ("hospitaldatabase");

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' .$_SESSION['listtype']. ' WHERE (ID_' .$_SESSION['listtype']. '="'.$_SESSION['id'].'")';
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $data = array(); 
    while($rows =  mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
         $data[] = $rows; 
    }
    return $data;
}

$myvars = extractFromId();
echo $myvars[0]['fieldname'];
```

As for undefined variables, it could be you've not called `session_start()` at the top of your pages before setting your `$_SESSION` variables. That would mean they are undefined.